# Order of the pole of the $ \int \limits_0^\infty\frac {\sin^4(x)} {x^4} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I have an integral $$
\int \limits_0^\infty\frac {\sin^4(x)} {x^4} \operatorname dx
$$

which is famous on this site, but I am not asking for the solution but for the explanation why I got at $x = 0$ pole of the third order, not the fourth order pole.

- L'Hospital? I tried third derivative where I got for $x = 0$ still $0/0$ and it doesn't work for the fourth derivative. But I am still missing the intuition behind it.

-Is there some rigorous way to determine the order of the poles if I am not sure?

Comment: What do you mean with pole for $x=0?$ The integral is just a number and does not depend on $x$.

Comment: But I have seen some examples where they were talking about poles. I want to use the contour integral and I am more confused than ever. :/

Comment: The question makes no sense. The integral is a number, not a function. Only functions, specifically holomorphic functions with isolated singularities, can have poles.

Comment: And If I write it as exponentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no pole at $x=0$. The integrand is

$$
\frac{(\sin x)^4}{x^4}=\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^4=(\operatorname{sinc}x)^4\;,
$$

and the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) is an [entire function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function).